# Use MediaWiki API to edit a web page on my local server

Tags: php, mediawiki, edit, mediawiki-api

I created a web page on my own local server using MediaWiki. The url is "http:\localhost\mediawiki\index.php\newPage". I intend to edit the page using the MediaWiki API in PHP, and plan to use API:edit. But how can I set the title or pageid parameter? Is there any other methods to edit this page on my local server using MediaWiki API?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set those values by editing a page.

The title is part of the identity of the page. To change the title, move the page, or edit a page at the new title.

The pageID is an internal identifier. It cannot be changed.

Comment: I mean I　want to edit this page's content, but I don't know how to access to that page. The example showing on MediaWiki API Main Page edits the page of Wikipedia, but I want to change a page created on my local server. How can I direct to my page? Thanks!

Comment: Use a URL to `api.php` on your own server. It's in the same directory as MediaWiki.